# How to Query a condition where one should exists and other should not exists in a Table in a single Query in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

how to check two attributes(id,mobileNumber) values  in a DynamoDb Table and check the condition Where id should exists and mobileNumber value should not exist in Dynamo Db in a single Query

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in [UpdateItem](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_item) with the ConditionExpression clause. In this case you'd use:
`ConditionExpression: {S: "attribute_exists(id) and attribute_not_exists(mobileNumber)"}`